# Install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch

Tags: puppet, installation, hiera

Installing puppet and hiera

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6.4/products/x86_64/puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch.rpm

sudo yum update -y

sudo yum -y install vim unzip rubygems puppet puppet-server hiera-puppet git
```

results in:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package hiera-puppet.noarch 0:1.0.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================
 Package           Arch        Version            Repository                Size
=================================================================================
Installing:
 hiera-puppet      noarch      1.0.0-1.el6        puppetlabs-products       14 k

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 14 k
Installed size: 14 k
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/extlookup2hiera from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/backend/puppet_backend.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/scope.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera_puppet.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_array.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_hash.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_include.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch
```

The question is how to solve the `install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.7.1-1.el6.noarch` issue.

A comparable issue was found [here](http://rnelson0.com/2014/06/30/puppet-installables-puppetdb-and-hiera/#more-536). However, the solution i.e `upgrading puppet from version 3.4.2 to 3.4.3` is not applicable to this issue.

```
Depending on your versions, you may receive an error, though

Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hiera-puppet' returned 1:

Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/extlookup2hiera from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/backend/puppet_backend.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/scope.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera_puppet.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_array.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_hash.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_include.rb from install of hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package puppet-3.4.3-1.el6.noarch

Error Summary
-------------

That’s correct, there’s no Error Summary. This error appears to be because the hiera-puppet version has a conflict with puppet 3.4.2. Upgrading to 3.4.3 or higher resolved this issue.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet 3 includes hiera and doesn't need/require any additional packages being installed for it.